# JqGrid - Show or hide sort icons manually

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a JqGrid with two sortable columns, on click of that sortable column header I am re-loading the Grid by getting some sorted data. Since the sort is custom I want to show/hide sort icons.
When I click the header the asc or desc icons are showing since I am reloading the grid the icons are reset and showing asc icon always.

How to show/hide the asc and desc icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me

```
$("div[id='jqgh_list_somename'] .s-ico").show();
$("div[id='jqgh_list_somename'] .s-ico span").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
$("div[id='jqgh_list_somename'] .s-ico")
            .find("span[sort='asc']").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
```